# N-Gons on body mesh of robot character? Fix or Leave N-Gons?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm new to Blender and have been modelling a robot arm as part of a video game character that i'll be importing into Unity. When i bevel its edges it gives me N-Gons on some faces... Does this need to be fixed with the knife tool (creating circular edge loops around the arm)? I'm asking because its arms are technically a hard surface body and i feel like i'm making a newbie mistake by creating so many knife loop cuts (creating a lot of new polygons) to have a quad only mesh. Can i leave the mesh with N-Gons or does it need to be quad only?

[image: Robot Arm showing N-Gons]

Comment: Generally, for video games, n-gons aren't an absolute no-no. Game engines automatically triangulate meshes upon import, so they can be less of an issue than with renderers that work best with quad based geometry. That being said, the engine does it's best job picking where to triangulate from, which doesn't always perform ideally. You can "help it along" by doing certain things such as making sure n-gons are always on flat faces and away from edges. For example, you could inset the large faces you have selected to leave the n-gons right in the center of them. This will help mitigate issues.

Comment: +1 for fixing the geometry. you need to start thinking on how to use only quads so you can learn how to model and you'll have less problems in the future.